# way to transform reinforcement learning problems to bandit problems

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

I wonder what a general way looks like to transform reinforcement learning problems to bandit problems (especially contextual bandit problems)

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible to frame a contextual bandit (CB) problem as a reinforcement learning (RL) problem, because RL generalises CB by adding a time sequence and state progression (which you can make entirely random to match CB exactly). It is not possible to go the other way without losing some detail which may be important - it is definitely not possible to do so *in general* as you are asking. Perhaps give more details about the problem you are facing (use [edit] to add to question), in case there is some way to make it work in your case - e.g. setting discount factor $\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between CB and RL problems is the i.i.d. assumption on the context generation, as opposed to the fact that there is a transition model between states in RL.

States and contexts may be used interchangeably, but when context is used instead of states ones usually thinks of CB and iid generation, meanwhile when states are mentioned usually one thinks of RL and transition probabilities.

As mentioned in the comment, one way to translate RL problems in CB would be for example to set $\gamma = 0$ but in general the quality of the model that you get when translating RL to CB problem depends on the underlying generation model of the states/contexts.

If the contexts are not iid but you still assume this framing your problem as CB, you may be not be able to learn an optimal policy since you do not capture the evolution of the states in your model. It may be that you are still able to learn a policy but that probably would be an approximation of the optimal policy under the iid generation assumption.